# Command line interaction using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Rails application and am trying to communicate with a Java program via the CLI.

When I run the Java code using `system`:

```
system "java askQuestion"
```

it prompts for user input and waits for an answer, such as "What is your age?"

I want to pass a value in from a variable, and capture the output.

How can I interact with the CLI and run the command?

I did research but I couldn't find anything or I missed the correct term to search.

**Solution: IO.popen**

update -->
 I found here what exactly I want and share maybe help someone else too , http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/external-programs/

Comment: We need more information. How many inputs will the Java code need before it processes? Can you pipe input into it from STDIN? Can it read the responses from a file? You say you did research, but you don't tell us where you searched and why those didn't help, which doesn't help us; Tell us where you searched, why those did no good so we don't repeat your footsteps. I'd strongly recommend reading "[ask]" including all the links at the bottom of the page as your question is too broad and lacks detail.

Comment: Have you tried poking around in the `rails console` ? It sounds like what you're describing. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console (BTW - It can be really difficult when you're so new to a language that you don't even know the terms to search. It's easy to forget that :).)

Comment: Thanks, I will check "How to Ask". I manage to achieve what I want to do exactly using "IO.popen". I added solution to my post.

Answer (score 0):

[`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) just executes the command in a subshell, returning the result (`true`/`false`) of process start.

To catch the output, use [backticks (or `%x||`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60).

To interact with a shell, one might use [`IO#popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-popen), but in your case I would just stick to executing

```
output = `echo 37 | java askQuestion`
```

The above will pass the output of `echo` (37 in this particular case) to the Java process. The response of the Java process will be stored in the `output` variable.

Comment: I tried this   output = ` java askQuestion | "37" `  but it gives this error " sh: 1: '37' not found " .

Comment: Why on the Earth would you try to pipe output of java to `37`, instead of other way round?!